# Cannot run program "bash": Launching failed?

Tags: java, android, c, bash, android-ndk

I have imported an example from FMODProgrammersApi example and I have done the procedure of Cygwin and Android NDK but when i run my project it gives following error in console

```
14:53:34 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Recording ****
bash /ndk-build all 
Cannot run program "bash": Launching failed

Error: Program "bash" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_06/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_06/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_06/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\Wbem;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin;D:\ABHIJEET_ONYX\New_Android_Sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\eclipse;]

14:53:35 Build Finished (took 267ms)
```

Please help me ...
I have gone through this tutorial http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: find which directory bash is located in and add the directory to PATH

Comment: sorry suspectus not getting your point

Comment: when a command (e.g. bash) is submitted the location of the command is searched for in the list of directories contained in PATH. Hence `Error: Program "bash" not found in PATH`.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` If its not bash, good chances are you do not have bash installed in cygwin, so either install the same or 
whatever is output for `echo SHELL` make a link as `ln -s <output> c:\\waterever Path you have in $PATH\bash`
Then execute/run the thing you want to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bash command in Windows platforms by default.

You can install a git which has one bash command and set the git bin folder (such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin) into system/user's path environment